# Error Using Ninject in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I do the following steps:

1. Open VS Express 2013 for Web
2. Create Empty MVC 5 Project
3. Select Tools ➤ Library Package Manager ➤ Manage Nuget Package for Solutions
4. Install Ninject.MVC5.
5. When I run debug I saw this:
   [image: error using ninject]

I am so confuse with this error since I am new to MVC and Ninject. I already use assembly redirect because It's seem it use System.Web.Mvc version 3.0.0.0, but it's still error.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I had also this issue. Bu when I used web application instead using Empty project it worked for me.

Comment: I think its because of the some of dll references missing in one of the project. Can you remove that nuget pacakge clean your solution and again add that.

Comment: I already try using ASP.NET MVC Template. It worked too

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall ninject from your project and install it again:

Select Tools-> Library Package Manager-> Package Manager Console in Visual Studio to
open the NuGet command line and enter the following commands:

Install-Package Ninject

Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common

Install-Package Ninject.MVC5

If the error continues checks that the version of System.Web.Mvc is 5.0 not another.

Answer (score 0):

First, Unistall the ninject you have Install with this code

Uninstall-Package Ninject.MVC5.
Note: you put a dot(.) at the end of MVC5, i think that gave you the error.

Now, you can Install the package again with these following code

Install-Package Ninject.MVC5

resource: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/